# Getting 401-Unauthorized while getting photo using outlook REST API - java cliet

Tags: java, office365api, outlook-restapi

I am trying to retrieve user photo using outlook REST API(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/photo-rest-operations#UserphotooperationsGetphoto)

I got the access token following (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx)

but getting this error : any help?

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [Content-Length: 0, Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0, request-id: 6925fcab-9021-4059-af4b-4cbf130faea7, X-CalculatedBETarget: CY1PR0401MB1388.namprd04.prod.outlook.com, X-BackEndHttpStatus: 401, Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=87cb2447eae9401c80a96c497dff06a9; expires=Sat, 22-Apr-2017 07:56:53 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly, x-ms-diagnostics: 2000001;reason="The access token is acquired using an authentication method that is too weak to allow access for this application. Presented auth strength was 1, required is 2.";error_category="invalid_token",

code looks something like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

final String bearerToken = getBearerToken();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/photo/$value");
request.setHeader(javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + bearerToken);
request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
return IOUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity().getContent());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message. Instead of a **client_secret** in your request body, you need a **client_assertion**.

For more details, you can reference the blog [Building Daemon or Service Apps with Office 365 Mail, Calendar, and Contacts APIs (OAuth2 client credential flow)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/)

According to the API you call "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/photo/$value". It seems that you only want to get the photo for the current login user; if so, you can use [Authorization Code Grant Flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx) to get the token which will not require the client certificates.

**UPDATE#1**:

> Can this be done programmatically/API way

As far as I know, the consent need the user's or admin's interactivity.

```
https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={0}&resource={1}&redirect_uri={2}&prompt={3}
```

[image]

If you are developing a ASP.NET web application, you can reference the sample project [O365-WebApp-MultiTenant](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-MultiTenant).

BTW, when calling the API with app-token, you need to specify the user name.

e.g.

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users('user1@customdomain.onmicrosoft.com')/messages
```

**UPDATE#2**:

The 403 code when updating the photo using the app token is expected result.
[image]

As we can see from the figure above, updating the user photo requires the delegated permission "User.Read.Write". The app token does not have permission to update user's photo.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, thanks for your reply!  Let me give you my scenario = "it is a multi-tenant app which will allow updating user profile (display name, photo etc)"   After reading this it seems like I have to 1. Retrieve access token(for specific tenant) using and an X.509 certificate with a public/private key pair. 2. Build some kind of consent tool to install the app in tenant's directory.    I will try this route - mean while a question on #2 Can this be done programmatically/API way, yes of course if we know the admin credential for the tenant.

Comment: @Pallab, about question#2, I've updated it in my answer

Comment: Thanks very much for your response and i have followed you path gotten the Access_token that way and now I got into another problem: 
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{upn}/photo/$value returned a response status of 403 Forbidden

Comment: got the Access_token via admin consent and  but getting this when try to fetch photo for other user in tenant: 
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{upn}/photo/$value   {null: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden}{Cache-Control: private}{Transfer-Encoding: chunked}{Content-Type: application/json}{Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5}{request-id: ...}{client-request-id:..}{x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West US","Slice":"SliceA","ScaleUnit":"001","Host":"AGSFE_IN_0","ADSiteName":"WST"}}}{Duration: 1757.4868}{X-Powered-By: ASP.NET}{Date: Fri, 29 Apr 2016 22:23:20 GMT} - and writing  n java

Comment: @Pallab, did you use the administrator's user token or the application token? Admin consent is accepting the multi-tenant app can be used in this tenant, to access other user's photo, you should use the application token. See blog Building Daemon or Service Apps with Office 365 Mail, Calendar, and Contacts APIs (OAuth2 client credential flow)

Comment: Thanks . I used admin app token -after getting authorization_code (via admin consent). sent a request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/token  w/ these params: params.add("code", code_obtained);
params.add("client_id", <appId in azureAd>);
params.add("client_secret", <symmetric key in azure ad>);
params.add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
params.add("redirect_uri", getRedirectURI());  could read the displayName attr for a user in the tenant but not the photo w/the token, guess I have to use "client_assertion" following .  guidance-multitenant-identity-client-assertion

Comment: code + client_secret will return the user token, so what you used is the amin user token. 403 should be an expected error when using the user token to access other user's resource.

Comment: Please see my present state in answer

Comment: did you get a chance to look at it. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Pallab, see my update#2, BTW, since this is another issue, if the original issue is resolved, I suggest you closing this one and starting a new dedicated question to discuss.

Comment: Will do...Thanks and really appreciate your help!